# Display Resource Author/Owner on Index Page (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display the name of the author of a `Joke` below the text of that joke on my `jokes#index` page, but am doing something wrong.  A `User` `has_many` `jokes`, and a `joke` `belongs_to` a `User`.

Here's the erb for my `jokes#index`:

```
  <% @jokes.each do |joke| %>
    <h2 id="joke-title" style="margin-top: 50px">
      <%= joke.title %>
      <% if joke.kids == true %>
        <%= image_tag 'icon_kids_green.jpg', style: "height: 25px; margin-left: 10px" %>
      <% end %>
      <% if joke.mixed == true %>
        <%= image_tag 'icon_mixed_purple.jpg', style: "height: 25px; margin-left: 10px" %>
      <% end %>
    </h2>
    <p id="joke-body"><%= joke.body %></p>
    <p><strong>Submitted by: <%= User.find(joke.user).first_name %></strong></p>
    <% if current_user.admin && joke.approved == nil && joke.rejected == nil %>
      <%#= link_to do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>Approve Joke
      <%# end %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>Reject Joke
    <% end %>
    <% if current_user == joke.user || current_user.admin %>
      <%= link_to edit_joke_path(joke) do %>
        <span style="color: blue" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span><span style="color: blue">Edit Joke</span>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to joke_path(joke), data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>Delete Joke
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Here's the index definition on my `jokes_controller`:

```
  def index
    @jokes = Joke.all
  end
```

I feel like this should be a fairly simple ask, so I must be doing something very stupid.  The error message I'm getting is:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

This error is called on the line in my `erb` asking fro the user's name.

Comment: It seems your `joke.user_id` is nil. Could you please provide the output of  `joke.inspect`?

Comment: @retgoat, `joke.inspect` yields this: `"#<Joke id: 4, title: \"The Calculating Sheepdog\", body: \"After a talking sheepdog gets all the sheep in the...\", kids: true, mixed: true, approved: nil, rejected: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: \"2016-07-31 23:18:15\", updated_at: \"2016-07-31 23:18:15\">"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the user was `nil` because in my controller I had:

```
@user = current_user.id
```

When it should have been:

```
@joke.user = current_user
```

Rookie mistake.  Now the user is saving and the rest of the code works because that was the actual problem.

Comment: You also don't need to do `User.find(@joke.user)`. Unless the User lost himself :)